# What client-side checks does blockchain's android client do?

Tags: thin-clients, blockchain.info, android

Blockchain just came out with a great [Android client](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=piuk.blockchain), based on [bitcoin-wallet](https://code.google.com/p/bitcoin-wallet/).

In the description it says "No blockchain downlaod [sic.]". However, in the documentation of [their sources](https://github.com/zootreeves/My-Wallet-Android), they say "When run for the first time, the block chain needs to be downloaded".

I'd be optimistic and **guess** they download all headers, and fully check the transactions regarding the local wallet, ignoring the unrelated transactions. However this is just a guess and I'd like to know which checks does it actually do client side, and how much does it instead "just trust" [blockchain.info](https://blockchain.info/) (which is very reputable anyway, but still I'd rather know).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The quote in the documentation is a remnant from the http://code.google.com/p/bitcoin-wallet/ which the app was forked from.

At present it does not do any blockchain validation. I would like to have it so instead of downloading the full transactions from blockchain.info the client asks for the block hashes that contain transactions of interest. It can then download the full blocks from the p2p network and only the headers for other blocks to verify the proof of work. However this is not currently implemented.